# Cannot install Ruby Gems (Ubuntu 15.04) - "Network is unreachable"

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, jekyll, ubuntu-15.04

I'm trying to install Jekyll on a fresh Vultr VPS running Ubuntu 15.04. I have installed Apache2 manually for the time being (I intend to scrap it for NodeJS later).

I am trying to install Jekyll however it is giving me the following error:

```
********@************:~$ gem install jekyll
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENETUNREACH)
    Network is unreachable - sendto(2) for "2001:19f0:300:1704::6" port 53

********@************:~$ gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENETUNREACH)
    Network is unreachable - sendto(2) for "2001:19f0:300:1704::6" port 53
```

I have the latest version of ruby installed (as shown below), I've noticed in some other forums that I might have to install (downgrade) to ruby1.9.1-dev?

```
********@************:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

I am not sure what is happening, and I have searched and searched.

Could anyone please shed some light on my situation?

Comment: "`Network is unreachable`" is your clue. It might be temporary if the site is down, or it might be permanent due to a routing problem from your site/network/host. Whatever, it isn't a Ruby problem.

Comment: I have tried to ping other websites from the console, have even installed new programs, not sure if I am behind a proxy?

Comment: Same issue here, however even adding ipv6 to vultr doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

The "2001:19f0:300:1704::6" is ipv6 address of vultr vps's DNS server. You can add ipv6 address in the console of server management, restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some sort of issue with name resolution in Vultr's setup. As a temporary fix, try opening `/etc/resolv.conf` and putting the IPv6 nameserver IP *underneath* the IPv4 nameserver IP.

I'm seeking the wisdom Vultr forums and will hopefully update this answer with a more permanent fix if I get any good answers.